# Event Hub Listener - get all messages in one go

Tags: azure, message, azure-eventhub

I am testing an Event Hub.  The developers are pushing messages to the Event Hub.  I have built an Event Hub Listener to check all the messages are being sent/received correctly.  This is the design I used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-receive-eph

The issue I have is there are circa 4 million events on the event hub and the ProcessEventsAsync method seems to get called 4 or 5 times and then stops being called.

Is there a way I can just request to get only the messages added in the last X minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `EventProcessorHost`, you could directly read through all the events. That means you would call [`Receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubreceiver.receive?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubReceiver_Receive_System_Int32_) method directly to read a batch of events.

See [Direct consumer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide#direct-consumer) and [Service Bus Event Hubs Direct Receivers](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Event-Hub-Direct-Receivers-13fa95c6) for code examples.

There is no way to filter events by time (last X seconds), offsets are the only addressable space.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I tried used InitialOffsetProvider (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881020/how-to-set-the-eventprocessorhost-to-read-events-from-now-on-utc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but that wouldnt work. Is that because as you say there is no way to filter events by time?