# (Go) Azure Event Processor Host to read events from now?

Tags: go, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am using azure-event-hubs-go client to read events from an Azure IoTHub. I am creating an Event Processor Host and providing an Handler to process events (as show in the sample in https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go).

How do I set the Event Processor Host to receive events from current time onwards ? I do not see any option like InitialOffsetProvider to set the offset manually.

Ths is similar to [How to set the EventProcessorHost to read events from now on (UTC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881020/how-to-set-the-eventprocessorhost-to-read-events-from-now-on-utc/33908060) but this is very specifically for Go client.

Comment: Tany, I see it is not implemented yet. So might be worth [waiting for](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go/issues/85#issuecomment-494473104) @devigned to deal with.

Comment: Whoops, I misread your question and didn't see that you were using the EventProcessor. I agree with the above comment - that doesn't appear to be implemented yet.